# How to dynamic check if json object name exists

Tags: javascript

#### json

```
data = {"name": "chan", "age", "35"};
```

I have an array `fields = ['name', 'age', 'hobby']`, I want to run `for (var i in fields)`, and check if object exists, for example `data.fields[i]`, this code won't work, how to do that?

Comment: that's not json, that's just javascsript...

Comment: when you get json in JavaScript should be object, shouldn't it?

Comment: json is a text-format encoding for transmitting a JS data structure to other systems. if you're  writing js code, then it's not json - it's just javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object fields can also be referenced using square bracket notation

```
data[fields[i]]
```

You should probably use `hasOwnProperty` though (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)):

```
data.hasOwnProperty(fields[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation:

```
for (var i in fields) {
    data[fields[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object isn't a nested one, use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var data = {"name": "chan", "age": "35"};
var fields = ['name', 'age', 'hobby'];

var doesKeyExist = Object.keys(data).some(function(key){ return fields.indexOf(key) > -1 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j8p5mcks/)